Remaking Vue.prototype.$dbCon in a Vue 3 project
I'm refactoring a Vue 2 project into Vue 3, and honestly have little idea what I'm doing. I've somehow got most of it working, but I can't find a good replacement for Vue.prototype that fits the scenario.
dbConnector.js
dbConnector.install =  function(Vue, options) {
  console.log("Installing dbConnector... ");

  Vue.prototype.$dbCon = {
    testConnection: function() {
       return "Testing connection: Connector listening...";
    },
    requestViewData: function(caller, param) {
        var url = "dataRequest.php";
        return dbConnector.createGETPromise(caller, url, param);
    },
    ...
  }

}


Home.vue (child of app.vue)
  async mounted () {

    console.log("Testing PHP connection")
    // this.$store.commit('logger/addEntry', {message: "Testing PHP connection"})
    this.$dbCon.requestViewData(...)
    ...
}

main.js (in Vue 3 if it helps)
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'
import dbCon from './resource/dbConnector'

const app = createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(dbCon)
  .use(router)
  .mixin(dbCon)
  .mount('#app');

My personal best idea is using provide/inject, but I haven't had much luck with it
new dbConnector.js
dbConnector.install = function (Vue, options) {
  console.log("Installing dbConnector... ");
  var dbCon = {
    requestViewData: function(caller, param) {
        var url = "dataRequest.php";
        return dbConnector.createGETPromise(caller, url, param);
    },
    ...
   }
   provide('$dbCon', dbCon)
}

new home.vue

    console.log("Testing PHP connection")
    console.log("dbCon: ", inject('$dbCon'));
    //Retuns dbCon: undefined
    $dbCon.requestViewData(...)
    //Throws Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'requestViewData')


It's unclear what code looks like. provide('$dbCon', dbCon) - is it located at the top of the module? This is incorrect, it should be used in component setup, probably root component (App). Instead most commonly this is done in a plugin with app.provide(), see https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins . If you're limited to 1 connection and this is your own app, provide/inject is overengineering you won't benefit from. Just import dbCon  from a module. You can wrap it with useDbCon function to make it more flexible, you can change the way it works any moment

main.js has problems. You're trying to do the same thing with const app and var vm. It's either one or another . var vm won't work correctly. And use(dbCon) is a mistake because it's not a plugin

@EstusFlask I'm not surprised about main.js. This is the first time I've used Vue or seen the project, and I think the previous person was the same. I was able to take it out without issue (assuming I added .use(store) so it gets initialised). Once I know what I'm doing I'll remove the use statements too
Importing it from a module worked fine. I'm sure I tried that before but doesn't matter, it's working now. Thanks

I see. A thing that is provided to use() is a plugin. FWIW, it's possible to make inject work with use({ install(app) { app.provide('$dbCon', dbCon) } }), this is exactly how other plugins do, but it's overengineering in this case, as said. Better to use function useDbCon() { return dbCon } instead of inject() or direct import, and you can switch it to use inject() any moment if there's necessity, which will likely never happen

"Throws Cannot read properties of undefined" - consider providing the rest of component, could be that inject was used incorrectly, but at least there's a problem with your install() that you use provide() instead of app.provide()

As Estus said, using provide/inject is overengineering for what I needed and I could've just made dbCon accessible from the export of dbConnection.vue
